# Integer prepresentation for UUID4 in Golang

Tags: python, go, uuid

I'm trying to parse a UUID4 in Golang, but I need some specific info: The Integer representation.

In python I use:

```
uuid.uuid4().int
```

but in Golang it doesn't exist (or in any other uuid library that I googled).

Is there a way to parse a simple UUID into its integer representation?.

Comment: Parse a [16]byte into an integer for an uuid like https://github.com/serverhorror/uuid ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming your uuid type a string:

```
func main() {
    uuid := `25f64dba-634d-4613-9516-9ca61b161454`
    var i big.Int
    i.SetString(strings.Replace(uuid, "-", "", 4), 16)
    //or if your uuid is [16]byte
    //i.SetBytes(uuid[:])
    fmt.Println(i.String())
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/gm_y0EYUrn)

Comment: it will be a UUID type but the comment and  this answer I can now wrap something to do it. Thanks

Comment: You didn't specify what library you were using, or if you're on linux and reading `/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid` directly (which returns a formatted string).

Comment: I chedked golang own uuid library and go-uuid from google code. thanks anyway, now I can handle this.